# How to solve the error while uploading image to nodes?

Tags: 7, media

I have a content type and it has an image field. I'm using the [File Field Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module for the image field.

I **uploaded** images for some nodes via Drupal interface but then **deleted** them via **FTP**.

Then I'm trying to re-upload images to these nodes via Drupal but it gives this error and couldn't find anything to solve the problem.

[image]

How can I solve this problem via Drupal or via PHPMyAdmin etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Upload QC](https://www.drupal.org/project/upload_qc) module. Some details about it (from its project page):

> This module offers checks and validations for the process of uploading files. It extends the Drupal 7 core and helps avoid errors during file upload. You can now say good bye to ***PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 2: INSERT INTO {file_managed}.***
>
> WHO SHOULD USE
>
> This module is for you if:
>
> 1. you run into errors like this one PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 2: INSERT INTO {file_managed} OR PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ... for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed}.
> 2. you would like to add additional file upload validations that check for (a) file name length, (b) file name containing certain words/characters, (c) file name not containing certain words/characters.
> 3. Drupal and/or PHP upload size limit is not working for you and you would like to set it yourself in your admin section.

Looks like item "1." is pretty close to your issue, no?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I will try this module in a dev site and share the result. I couldn't use it in the live site because its "redness". Thanks.

Comment: No problem for being late, and of course such kind of experiments better happen in a DEV site (just curious if you'll be able to recreate the problem there to start with). Anyway, keep my updated after you had a chance to look at it ...

Comment: Did you ever have a chance to try this?

Comment: Yes I tried it but didn't work for me, unfortunately. I had to clear the related databases manually.